# how to concatenate these two regular expression in one

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using regular expression validation in asp.net and have two regular expressions
First is to prevent special characters
`[A-Za-z0-9_]+`
Second is to validate min max range
`(\s|.){6,15}`

I want to merge these tow in one validation expression, please suggest me how I can do it

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9_\s]{6,15}` something like this perhaps?

Comment: Putting some sample data which the regular expression should validate and reject would be useful deciding on the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
"[A-Za-z0-9_\s]{6,15}"
```

is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correct:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]{6,15}
```